# Redirect and rewrite based on domain name

Tags: redirect, nginx, magento-1.7

## What I need to get working:

I need to redirect based on the domain name from the request, and once the redirection has occurred I need to rewrite the url so that users only see that domain name in the url.

#### Specifics

My site currently has the domain name `example.com` and I have a second domain name `different.com` that I need to redirect traffic to a specific url. This url will switch to a different store view: `example.com?___store=differentstore`

The switching is working fine, but I need to figure out how to setup a rule in nginx that will watch for the `different.com` and then redirect to the above url but from that point rewrite the url to `different.com` so that those users never see `example.com`.

The only time I need the `?___store=differentstore` is on the initial entry with `different.com` as the host. From that point on users won't be able to see the default view (for example.com) unless they browse to the `example.com` domain

## What I've tried:

This is what I have tried so far and it isn't working:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name www.different.com different.com;
   return 301 http://www.example.com?___store=different;

   if ($http_host != "www.example.com" && $http_host != "example.com") {
             rewrite ^ http://different.com$request_uri;
}
```

### Details

- LEMP stack
- Magento 1.7